# how to index a many to many relation by sphinx

Tags: join, many-to-many, sphinx

I have a question about index a many to many relation.
e.g:

```
table A : id,value_a(string)
table B : id,value_b(string)
table C: id_a,id.b,value_c(string)
```

the query is :

```
select * from C where C.id_a = A.id And A.value_a like keyword_a
         and C.id_b = B.id andB.value_b like keyword_b
```

so i want to index table A and table B with full-text search by sphinx,but I can not find
a method to join two
search result to table C .

can anyone help me ? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an index with all the data

```
sql_query = select C.id,id_a,id_b,value_a,value_b,value_c \
       from C \
       inner join A on (C.id_a = A.id) \
       inner join B on (C.id_b = B.id)
sql_attr_uint = id_a
sql_attr_uint = id_b
```

by storing id_a and id_b in the index as attributes, can group by (at search time) to only get one document per A or B.

btw, a query would be something like

```
$cl->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$res = $cl->Query('@value_a keyword_a @value_b keyword_b',$sphinx_index);
```

Comment: But my database is mongodb .I build my index through xmlpipe2 by reading mongodb.I dont want to build a full data index because there is too much redundancy data.So is there a way to  not need to build a full data ? not MVA ,because value_a and value_b are all strings about 100 characters.

Comment: Sphinx doesnt actully store the text, it tokenizes it and builds inverted index. So worrying about 'redundancy' is not required. You may be used to the idea of "Normalaizing" when dealing with databases. But for sphinx you should DEnormalize to index your data. What I showed works just as well with xmlpipe.

Comment: Thank you very much @barryhunter.You help me a lot.It's clear now that i dont need to worry about 'redundancy'.